# What's the correct way to compute this limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

So in a math test, I was asked to prove that the following limit is equal to $0$ :

$$ \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x²}{\sqrt{x²} +  1} + 2 - (-x + 2)$$ Given $x$ < 0

The way I solved this was that way :

$$ \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x²}{\sqrt{x²} } + 2 - (-x + 2)$$

I took the biggest exponent on the denominator, In this case $\lim_{x\to \infty} {\sqrt{x²} +  1} = \lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt{x²}$ as $ + 1$ wouldn't do any harm to our limit

After that I did this :

$$ \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x²}{-x } + 2 - (-x + 2) $$

$$ \lim_{x\to \infty} -x + 2 + x - 2 $$

And that would leave us with this :

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} x-x = 0 $$

However a math teacher I knew told me that my approach was incorrect because $\lim_{x\to \infty} x - x$ is an indeterminated form which isn't as some math folks over here answered about this problem . I would like to know whether my approach was correct, if ot isn't then why ?

Comment: Why did you do $\sqrt{x^2}=-x$?

Comment: @imranfat Because x is negative so $\sqrt{x²} = |x| = -x  $

Comment: Your limit says $x$ goes to infinity, so $x$ is not negative in the limit. The limit as it stands in fact does not exist

Comment: This limit is not 0, actually it does not even exist. What does even $x <0$ mean if your limit goes to infinity? It is a contradiction.

Comment: If we reconcile the problematic conjunction of $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}$ and $x<0$ by making it $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}$, then the problem is not that $\lim\limits_{x\to -\infty}(x-x)$ were an indeterminate form (it isn't). The problem is where you replaced $\dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2}+1}$ with $\dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2}}$. Let's take a look. For $x<0$, we have $$\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2}+1} + 2 -(-x+2) = \frac{\lvert x\rvert^2}{\lvert x\rvert + 1} + 2 - \lvert x\rvert - 2 = \frac{\lvert x\rvert^2 - \lvert x\rvert(\lvert x\rvert + 1)}{\lvert x\rvert + 1} = -\frac{\lvert x\rvert}{\lvert x\rvert+1}.$$